# Is there any built-in function in moment/moment-timezone to convert from a timezone name to a "human readable format"?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, moment-timezone

Take as an example the following [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-moment-moment-timezone-convert-to-human-readable?embed=1&file=index.ts) of a project I'm working on where I receive a timezone name and I need to convert it to a "human-readable format".

i.e.:

- input: `America/Los_Angeles`
- output: `America Los Angeles`

I now, you may consider "America/Los_Angeles" is already "human-readable" and I agree, but it's a requirement of my issue to convert it to the mentioned format (or similar, without including slashes, underscores, etc).

Also, this could be achieved easily using a regular expression, but as [moment](https://momentjs.com/) and [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) are being used as part of the project... I wonder, is there a way to do achieve this using any built-in mechanism provided by any of these libraries?

---

```
import 'moment-timezone';
import * as moment from 'moment';

const tz = moment.tz.zone("America/Los_Angeles");

const result = tz.name;

console.log(result);  // America/Los_Angeles, need "America Los Angeles"
```

If it is of any help, this is in an Angular project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed in [the docs on formatting](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/):

> Moment.js also provides a hook for the long form time zone name. Because these strings are generally localized, Moment Timezone does not provide any long names for zones.
>
> To provide long form names, you can override `moment.fn.zoneName` and use the `zz` token.

```
var abbrs = {
    EST : 'Eastern Standard Time',
    EDT : 'Eastern Daylight Time',
    CST : 'Central Standard Time',
    CDT : 'Central Daylight Time',
    MST : 'Mountain Standard Time',
    MDT : 'Mountain Daylight Time',
    PST : 'Pacific Standard Time',
    PDT : 'Pacific Daylight Time',
};

moment.fn.zoneName = function () {
    var abbr = this.zoneAbbr();
    return abbrs[abbr] || abbr;
};

moment.tz([2012, 0], 'America/New_York').format('zz');    // Eastern Standard Time
moment.tz([2012, 5], 'America/New_York').format('zz');    // Eastern Daylight Time
moment.tz([2012, 0], 'America/Los_Angeles').format('zz'); // Pacific Standard Time
moment.tz([2012, 5], 'America/Los_Angeles').format('zz'); // Pacific Daylight Time
```